# "lea" command in bomb lab phase 4

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

This is my first month of doing assembly and I've been tasked with solving the infamous bomb lab. I've gotten some heavy progress done today but for the life of me I can't figure out exactly what's going on in phase 4. I can tell that it wants an input of two integers (I believe the second one is supposed to be 35?) but I can't figure out some parts of the recursive function it calls. I've commented every line to the best of my ability.

Here's the assembly for the 4th phase:

```
000000000040103f <phase_4>:
  40103f:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp                //INPUT 2 INTEGERS     //ANSWER = 
  401043:   48 8d 4c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
  401048:   48 8d 54 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
  40104d:   be 0d 28 40 00          mov    $0x40280d,%esi        //This is our numbers, they get put into %esi
  401052:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax            //%eax = 0
  401057:   e8 d4 fb ff ff          callq  400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>     //scan in the input
  40105c:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax            //make sure there are two integers
  40105f:   75 07                   jne    401068 <phase_4+0x29>        //if there are not 2 integers, jump to bomb
  401061:   83 7c 24 0c 0e          cmpl   $0xe,0xc(%rsp)           // 0xc(%rsp) == 12? (x/s $rsp gives "h\342\377\377\377\177")
  401066:   76 05                   jbe    40106d <phase_4+0x2e> //jump past the detonation
  401068:   e8 17 05 00 00          callq  401584 <explode_bomb>    //BOOM
  40106d:   ba 0e 00 00 00          mov    $0xe,%edx            //%edx = 0xe (14)
  401072:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi            //%esi = 0
  401077:   8b 7c 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi           //%edi = 0xc(%rsp)
  40107b:   e8 8c ff ff ff          callq  40100c <func4>           //call fun4
  401080:   83 f8 23                cmp    $0x23,%eax           //%eax == 35?
  401083:   75 07                   jne    40108c <phase_4+0x4d>        //if %eax != 35, jump to detonation
  401085:   83 7c 24 08 23          cmpl   $0x23,0x8(%rsp)              //0x8(%rsp) == 35?
  40108a:   74 05                   je     401091 <phase_4+0x52>        //if so, jump past the detonation
  40108c:   e8 f3 04 00 00          callq  401584 <explode_bomb>        //BOOM
  401091:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp           //%rsp = 18
  401095:   c3                      retq                    //phase 4 disarmed
```

and here's the assembly for func4, the recursive math function that does some shenanigans:

```
000000000040100c <func4>:
  40100c:   53                      push   %rbx
  40100d:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax            //%eax = %edx
  40100f:   29 f0                   sub    %esi,%eax            //%eax -= %esi
  401011:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx            //%ebx = eax
  401013:   c1 eb 1f                shr    $0x1f,%ebx           //shift %ebx right by 0x1f (31)
  401016:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax            //%eax += %ebx
  401018:   d1 f8                   sar    %eax                 //shift %eax right by 1
  40101a:   8d 1c 30                lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx   //???
  40101d:   39 fb                   cmp    %edi,%ebx          //compare %edi and %ebx
  40101f:   7e 0c                   jle    40102d <func4+0x21>  //if %edi < %ebx, jump to 40102d
  401021:   8d 53 ff                lea    -0x1(%rbx),%edx      //???
  401024:   e8 e3 ff ff ff          callq  40100c <func4>       //RECURSE
  401029:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax            //%eax += %ebx
  40102b:   eb 10                   jmp    40103d <func4+0x31>  //jump to 40103d (done)
  40102d:   89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax            //%eax = %ebx
  40102f:   39 fb                   cmp    %edi,%ebx          //compare %edi and %ebx
  401031:   7d 0a                   jge    40103d <func4+0x31>  //if %edi > %ebx, jump to 40103d (done)
  401033:   8d 73 01                lea    0x1(%rbx),%esi       //???
  401036:   e8 d1 ff ff ff          callq  40100c <func4>       //RECURSE
  40103b:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax            //%eax += %ebx
  40103d:   5b                      pop    %rbx                 //done.
  40103e:   c3                      retq
```

I see the gist of what's going on here (a bunch of math in a recursive function.) But I really don't understand what the lea command  (such as lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx)  is doing in this instance. I know it's called "load effective address" and what it does *in general*, but not what it does here.

Comment: That uses a base, index and scale computation and places it in EBX. So it is EBX = RAX+RSI*1. Basically add RAX to RSI and stores it to EBX. LEA simply means Load Effective Address. LEA doesn't access memory, it simply was designed to help compute memory addresses, but in essence it can do simple math type operations for any purpose.

Comment: You can learn what instructions do by looking at an [instruction set reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/)

Comment: Alright cool. So 0x1(%rbx),%esi would mean   %esi = 1 * %rbx, then?

Comment: `lea 0x1(%rbx),%esi` would be ESI=1+RBX. It is displacement(base, index, scale). The computation is displacement + base + index * scale).

Answer (score -1):

At this point, you seem to have the pseudocode down for what this program does. Your next step is to walk all the way through this program. Once you know what the end result should be, you should be able to walk backwards and reverse engineer your input. Make sure you know what commands use which addresses, and you should be good.

While walking through this, use commands like "i r" in gdb and "layout reg" to check the values of your registers and variables. Good luck!